# View Bound methods, ordered Trait and implicit converting

Tags: scala, sorting

If I have a method that has the following signature:

```
def max[T <% Ordered[T]](list:List[T]): T={ 
 //return max. element of List (for example)
}
```

and I want to give a list of pairs like this to it:

```
val fu:List[Pair[String, Double]] = List(Pair("a", 3.1),Pair("b", 1.7),Pair("c", 3.1),Pair("d", 5.4))
```

How do I define the ordering on the second element of the list, so I am able to work with it in the function?

I tried to use

```
implicit def wrapper(p: Pair[String, Double])=new runtime.RichDouble(p._2)
```

to implicitly convert the Double of the Pair to a RichDouble which extends the ordered trait, but that is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

given:

```
scala> def max[T <% Ordered[T]](xs: List[T]) = xs.max
max: [T](xs: List[T])(implicit evidence$1: T => Ordered[T])T

scala> case class Pair(x: String, y: Double)
defined class Pair
```

You need to define ordering object for `Pair`:

```
scala> implicit val order = scala.math.Ordering.by[Pair, Double](_.y)
order: scala.math.Ordering[Pair] = scala.math.Ordering$$anon$7@3b2e9a90
```

Then you will find your `max` function working for `Pair`s

```
scala> max(List(Pair("foo", 1), Pair("bar", 2), Pair("baz", 2.2)))
res5: Pair = Pair(baz,2.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use `maxBy`?

```
scala> val xs = ('c',3) :: ('a',1) :: ('b',2) :: Nil

scala> val x = xs maxBy(_._2)

//x == ('c',3)
```

Comment: the max thing was just an example :) I wanted to use the ordering of the elements in the function.